# Javascript datetime strings ignoring timezone offset (experiment)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, timezone, momentjs

My worst nightmare are date objects, so I've created a fiddle to see how it works, and try to find a solution for **date strings** in the following format `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z` but taking care of current timezone.

Basically, I want to be able to write `new Date()` (or similar) and get `2015-10-05T09:49:13.587Z` instead of `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z`.

It seems that the only methods displaying the correct date/time are:

- `moment().format()`
- `new Date().toLocaleString()`
- `moment().toLocaleString()`
- `moment().format().toLocaleString()`

But none of them are returning a date object like the one I want. What's the proper method to deal with it then?

Please, check my tests: **http://codepen.io/Frondor/pen/PPmYpv**

[image]

Comment: deal with what? You haven't identified what you are wanting or trying to do or what your specific problem is

Comment: As I stated above "... and try to find a solution for date objects in the following format `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z`". Basically, I want to be able to write `new Date()` and get `2015-10-05T09:49:13.587Z` instead of `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z`

Comment: then you need to use UTC . Note that you are showing strings, not object. The `Date` object can be used to get whatever string you need out of it. String and object are not the same thing

Comment: I already edited the question and added the specific problem, don't flag it for god sake. I'm just confused! Show me how to use UTC so

Comment: Look at moment docs for UTC. Or read Date docs for UTC

Comment: Things like `moment.utc()` or `moment.utc().format()` will still display an incorrect time for me... moment.js by default displays local time (which isn't totally true), `moment.utc()` won't display local time at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, I want to be able to write `new Date()` (or similar) and get `2015-10-05T09:49:13.587Z` instead of `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z`.

The value you're asking for is two hours earlier.  It would be invalid to convert it in this way.

I think you are confusing two very different things:

- UTC is not a format.  It is a system of timekeeping.  When we say "in UTC", we mean that the time value is presented in Universal Time - which is the same all over the planet, and is roughly the same as GMT (the time in Greenwich, England without considering daylight saving time).  If you're local time is two hours behind UTC, then UTC is two hours ahead of your local time.
- The ISO-8601 format is a string representation for dates and times.  There are several forms, and the one you've expressed is the *extended format* of a *timestamp*.  In other words, it represents the actual instant that an event occurs, in terms of a date, a time, and a relationship to UTC.

  In this format, the `Z` specifically means "the value presented here is already in terms of UTC".  It is roughly the same as using `+00:00`.

Therefore, if the value in UTC as an ISO8601 string is `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z`, then the corresponding local value (assuming UTC-2 as you stated), is `2015-10-05T09:49:13.587-02:00`.  This is still in ISO8601 format, but is no longer in UTC.

The easiest way to get this is with moment.js, using `moment().format()`.

Answer (score 1):

This format - `2015-10-05T11:49:13.587Z` - is one of the standard representation of date and time in [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) or the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The timezone will not be shown in this format because the purpose of the format itself is (as explained in the Wikipedia article):

> Representation of dates and times is an international standard
>   covering the exchange of date and time-related data.

But we can definitely show the date in that format along with the offset for the current timezone, but it defeats the purpose of that "standard" format itself.

Comment: So I won't be able to do something like `new Date()` and display a date and time in ISO 8601 format which takes in mind the current timezone? And of course, output that kind of standard representation?

Comment: You can (see my answer) but it would be interpreted by other consumers as a UTC time, not a local time. As long as the code that generates and consumes this string both agree on this format, it will work, but other consumers would misinterpret the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for it to produce an inaccurate time. The format you're looking for implies a time in UTC. I would suggest you review your requirement, as there may be a flaw there. 
But if that's exactly what you want, you would say:
`moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSS") + 'Z'`

Comment: I hope you can see why this would be considered "incorrect" by most developers. I agree with you (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32460882/149884), dates and times are a real pain (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/296904/why-isnt-there-a-true-date-only-data-type). but you're looking for more pain if you try to fight the system.